# English words that can be only used as nouns

Tags: english, terminology, parts-of-speech, nouns

Is there a term for words that can be only used as nouns?
For example, I think "history" and "sofa" are such words, but "book" and "dog" are not.

I'm looking for a list (preferably with frequency/commonality) of such words, but I don't even know which term to look up.

Comment: All nouns can be verbed. Verbing weirds language.

Comment: I can understand this notion in general, but aren't well-known dictionaries (e.g. Oxford) list some words as nouns only and others as noun and some other parts of speech (e.g. verb)?
Like here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/history?q=history

Comment: @AviaEfrat Dictionaries describe usage; if "history" or "sofa" became a commonly used verb somewhere in the English-speaking world, the Oxford English Dictionary would list it as a verb. As far as I know, there is nothing grammatically different about those words which stops them being used that way, we just don't happen to need them right now.

Comment: @IMSoP I don't think this settles the question. There are the terms [polysemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) and [monosemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosemy) for words that have multiple meanings and one meaning respectively, even though any word with just one meaning may acquire further meanings along the way; so there could logically be parallel terms for words that can act as multiple parts of speech, and those that can't.

Comment: @LjL That's true; within a particular dictionary or word list, you could determine a subset of nouns which had no corresponding verb entry (matched by spelling I guess?). In order for there to be an accepted term for that list, though, it would need to have some linguistic importance or relevance, and I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: @IMSoP well, what is the linguistic relevance of monosemy vs polysemy? Sometimes humans also just like to classify things into categories they can discern... Anyway, I see relevance, for instance, in computational linguistics, in any situation where a word needs to be disambiguated. With monosemy vs polysemy the code must guess the correct meaning from context; with parts of speech, it must, well, guess the part of speech, which is relevant to anything that parses a sentence's grammar.

Comment: @LjL "what is the linguistic relevance of monosemy vs polysemy?" - according to the two Wikipedia articles you linked, quite a lot. But yes, there might be a reason why someone's given this concept a name; I just don't think the OP should hold their breath waiting for one.

Comment: I see no prospects for empirically establishing such words. Omission from dictionaries is not evidence ("food" is not used as a verb). *Who* can't use 'history' as a verb? The implication is that no person at all can: and how do we establish that?

Comment: Shakespeare certainly did (use history as a verb) 1600   W. Shakespeare Henry IV, Pt. 2 iv. i. 201   And keepe no tel-tale to his memorie, That may repeate, and history his losse, To new remembrance. see the relevant entries in the OED and Unabridged MW (history2, v, obsolete)

Comment: @colin maybe we can eventually make language a complete impediment to understanding.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: certain writers try very hard to do this. Ordinary speakers, not so much.